# Select 3 tablas mysql

Tags: mysql

Quisiera saber como hacer para traer los registros de 3 tablas en mysql:

```
Tabla1 ->Causa|Fecha|Tipo|Usuario
Tabla2 ->Causa|Fecha|Tipo|Usuario
Tabla3 ->Causa|Fecha|Tipo|Usuario
```

Y quisiera traer un solo listado `Causa|Fecha|Tipo|Usuario` con el contenido de las 3. Pero no se como hacer el `Select`.

Aclaro que Los datos en cualquiera de los 4 campos pueden ser diferentes.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: no le puedo ayudar mucho, su respuesta no es muy concreta y falta mas datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que se puede entender o lo que yo pude entender, tu solución se podría realizar con la clausula UNNION ALL un ejemplo seria el siguiente:

```
(
SELECT
sonido.nombre AS S,
sonido.ruta AS R
FROM
sud_cat
INNER JOIN sonido ON sonido.id_cat = sud_cat.id_sub_cat
WHERE sud_cat.sub_cat = 'Intro'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT
video.nombre AS S,
video.fech_sub AS R
FROM
sud_cat
INNER JOIN video ON video.id_cat = sud_cat.id_sub_cat
WHERE sud_cat.sub_cat = 'Video'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
)
UNION ALL 
(
SELECT
sonido.nombre AS S,
sonido.ruta AS R
FROM
sud_cat
INNER JOIN sonido ON sonido.id_cat = sud_cat.id_sub_cat
WHERE sud_cat.sub_cat = 'Fin'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
)
```

Algo que tiene que tener muy en cuenta es lo siguiente, si puede notar en mi consulta traigo solo 2 parámetros a los cuales re nombro como S y R, esto es muy importante, ya que tienen que tener la misma cabecera para que este pueda hacer la consulta y agruparla en la cantidad de columnas que establezcas.

El resultado en mi caso seria el siguiente:

```
-- ----------------- Primera consulta ---------------
"Intro_07.mp3"  "./assets/archivos/Intro/Intro_07.mp3"
"Intro_08.mp3"  "./assets/archivos/Intro/Intro_08.mp3"
"Intro_13.mp3"  "./assets/archivos/Intro/Intro_13.mp3"
-- ----------------- Segunda consulta ---------------
"video_16.mp4"  "2018-05-12 16:57:03"
"video_21.mp4"  "2018-05-12 17:01:29"
"video_12.mp4"  "2018-04-19 13:48:22"
-- ----------------- Tercera consulta ---------------
"Fin_09.mp3"    "./assets/archivos/Fin/Fin_09.mp3"
"Fin_08.mp3"    "./assets/archivos/Fin/Fin_08.mp3"
"Fin_07.mp3"    "./assets/archivos/Fin/Fin_07.mp3"
```

Answer (score 5):

Para lo que necesitas puedes usar el operador `UNION`

```
SELECT Causa,Fecha,Tipo,Usuario FROM Tabla1
UNION
SELECT Causa,Fecha,Tipo,Usuario FROM Tabla2
UNION
SELECT Causa,Fecha,Tipo,Usuario FROM Tabla3;
```

El operador `UNION` se utiliza para combinar el conjunto de resultados de dos o más instrucciones `SELECT`.

Debes tener en cuenta que:

- Cada instrucción `SELECT` dentro de `UNION` debe tener el mismo número de columnas
- Las columnas también deben tener tipos de datos similares
- Las columnas en cada declaración `SELECT` también deben estar en el mismo orden.

---

Más info en la [documentación oficial de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) y en la [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Solucionado. ;)

Comment: Genial!, de nada :)